# Why can't perl see a file that exists in windows?

Tags: windows, perl

On one of my coleagues machine, if you just look for java you can find it:

```
c:\>where java 
C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
```

However, if I do this test in perl:

```
c:\>perl -e "print (-e 'c:\\windows\\system32\\java.exe' ? 'found' : 'not found')"
not found
```

(this runs fine on my machine). I've heard about some sort of weird cache where files get fake-installed so they sort-of-work, but I have no idea what it could be called and nothing I've googled helps.

Comment: Probably WOW64 filesystem redirection if you're running a 32-bit Perl on 64-bit Windows - accesses to `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` will be redirected to `%SYSTEMROOT%\Syswow64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment to the question by Andrew Medico, the problem was confusion caused by running 32-bit perl.

The system in question had "c:\windows\system32\java.exe", but did not have "c:\windows\syswow64\java.exe". I was able to solve my problem by looking for "c:\windows\sysnative\java.exe" if "c:\windows\system32\java.exe" did not appear to exist.

I found this description very helpful:

http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm